# Python regex matching all the characters with character set

Tags: python, regex

I want to use match all the characters in a string with a set of characters and if any of the character in string is not matching, it should not match. I am using character set and I want all the charcters in string to match character set. But in case if any additional charater is present, it passes.

How can i fix it?

```
>>> re.search(r'[a-z]*','abcA')  
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x026DBBB8> ===> Should FAIL
>>> re.search(r'[a-z]*','abc')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x026DBBF0>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Anchor the regex to restrict it.   `r'^[a-z]*$'`

Comment: 3 votes in under three minutes, wow that must be a speed record.

Answer (score 2):

`re.search(r'^[a-z]*$','abcA')` This will do the job. `^` implies the start of a string, while `$` implies the end of a string.